# Download images from a web directory without knowing the names of the image itself?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I would like to know if it is possible to download every image from a directory without knowing the name of the images?

I am trying to download all images from this directory

/www.metservice.com/IcePics/ob/

This is one of the images

> http://www.metservice.com/IcePics/ob/249a-1341bdfd0e0-1341be2b97f.ImgPlayerAUCKLAND.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Of course it's possible. Write some code to fetch the directory listing, parse out the links, and fetch each one in sequence.

Comment: okay cool! that gives me a good starting point never even knew you could fetch a directory listing".. I have also read that you can use a Predicate to limit the file type etc :) So going to look into this with ASIHTTPRequest

Comment: You provided us with the directory listing, http://www.metservice.com/IcePics/ob/, *in your question*.

Comment: indeed :) I just need to figure out what parameter that needs to go into what for the asihttprequest methods. Then its all a mater of restricting the images I want for with some type of predicate based off the image names :) I will have a play around with it today :) If i make any break throughs I